# how to prove: $ \sin^4\theta =\frac{3}{8} - \frac{1}{2}\cos2\theta + \frac{1}{8}\cos4\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

How can I prove this? 
$ \sin^4\theta =\frac{3}{8} - \frac{1}{2}\cos2\theta + \frac{1}{8}\cos4\theta$

Comment: Start from the RHS and expand?

Comment: Could use complex numbers $z+z^{-1}=2\cos(\theta)$ and $z-z^{-1}=2i\sin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

From `left to right`, start from thee complex exponential definition of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$:
$$\sin\theta=\tfrac1{2i}(\mathrm e^{i\theta}-\mathrm e^{-i\theta}),\qquad \cos \theta=\tfrac1{2}(\mathrm e^{i\theta}+\mathrm e^{-i\theta})$$
whence  $$\sin^4\theta=\frac1{16}\bigl(\mathrm e^{i\theta}-\mathrm e^{-i\theta}\bigr)^{\mkern-2mu4},$$
which you can expand by the binomial formula.

With *pure trigonometry* (always from left to right), use the linearisation formulæ:
\begin{align}
\sin^4\theta&=\Bigl(\tfrac12(1-\cos 2\theta)\Bigl)^2=\tfrac14(1-2\cos 2\theta+\cos^22\theta)\\
&=\tfrac14\Bigl(1-2\cos 2\theta+\tfrac12(1+\cos4\theta)\Bigr)=\dotsm
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Use that $$\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$$
$$\cos(4x)=1-2\sin^2(2x)$$
$$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. Use $\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$ twice on $\cos4x$, then also $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$ and then trasform all $\sin^2x$ terms to $\cos^2x$ terms (or vice versa of course) and you obtain an equation with just multiples of $1,\cos^2(x),\cos^4(x)$.